# If I am running a dotnetcore webservice in IIS - do I need to enable CORS module in IIS and allow CORS in my app?

Tags: iis, .net-core, cors, iis-10

If I am running a dotnetcore webservice in IIS - do I need to enable CORS module for IIS and also allow CORS in my app via code? Or should just the IIS CORS module suffice?
I can't make heads or tails of what seems to be happening.

Comment: You can allow CORS through code, or you can allow CORS by installing the IIS CORS module.

Answer (score -1):

CORS is just a set of headers that browsers read.

You can configure it in your web.config and enable IIS module or configure and add middleware in your .net webservice. It probably depends on your usage scenario. It's a bit more portable if configured internally in the .net app.

Example config:

```cs
services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
    policy.WithOrigins(Configuration.GetSection("AllowedOrigins").Get<string[]>())
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
});

...

app.UseCors();
```